# Src to DataURL seems incorrect

Tags: javascript

I found this code online and it seems to work pretty well.

But I am confused as what the last part is for.

```
function toDataUrl(src, callback, outputFormat) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
  };
  img.src = src;
  if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
    img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
    img.src = src;
  }
}
```

The img already has the src that was passed assigned to it.  Then, if complete or complete undefined (not sure what this is for), img.src has some other dataURL assigned to it.  I would assume this would overwrite the original assignment and then the passed in src is assigned to it again????

It does work, but I was curious as to what it is doing?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Not sure, but I guess the if-part is used to trigger the img.onload event in case it was already fired. Does it work if you remove the last three lines?

Comment: what shows if the src is updated using the "if block"

Comment: Yes, it works if I comment out the last 4 lines.  If I only comment out the last "img.srs = src;" line, it doesn't come back with anything.  So maybe those lines are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The last part is adding a 1px Gif to the img incase the img is not completely filled. The assigning of src again is kind of a retry

Comment: But doesn't the assigning of the src again overwrite the 1px Gif?

Comment: that's what I said its kind of a retry... you should modify it to some appropriate solution